# IdentityServer4 + JWT: Define user property for "sub" claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 with JWT and ASP.NET Core 2 for authentication. I'm also using `IdentityUser<long>` (`long` primary key instead of `string`) as user model because of performance issues for big queries. That has the effect that I got an ordered user ID that will given by default to public, inside the encoded access token. The use of GUID as default type has it's reason and because of that I would want to give out to public only a GUID, not an ordered integer. For that I have an extra `ExternalID` column of type GUID that will be generated once when the user is created.

Now I need to replace the `sub` claim where by default the integer `Id` is used with my `ExternalId` (GUID).

I tried using a `ProfileService` with the following `GetProfileDataAsync` method

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
    var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);

    var claims = principal.Claims.Where(
        claim => 
        claim.Type != "sub" && 
        context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(claim.Type))
        .ToList();

    claims.Add(new Claim("sub", user.ExternalId.ToString()));

    context.IssuedClaims = claims;
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
   // ...
   .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

But that has no effect. `IssuedClaims` seems to be ignored. The token still contains the `Id` at `sub` claim not `ExternalId`.

What am I missing? Is that the right approach?

Comment: Just to be sure - have you verified that your `GetProfileDataAsync()` method is being called?

Comment: Yes, it's definitly been called when the user logs in for the first time.

Comment: It's not been called for refresh token exchange.

Comment: I was able to get this working, by extending the UserClaimsPrincipleFactory in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity package.  At least for the most part.  When getting an id_token by first hitting the ResourceOwnerPassword endpoint, then the UserInfo enpoint, I would recieve a forbidden error. The sub claim from the access_token was still showing the int value, while the id_token was showing the GUID. The conflict caused an error. When gaining an access token through oidc with the hybrid flow, the sub claim would come back correctly.  If you can solve that issue, I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working despite my comment above and have seen no side effects. At least none I can see yet.  You will need to replace the sub claim in two locations.

First extend Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipleFactory like so.  This will modify the claim prior to recieving an Id Token.

```
public sealed class MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>
{
    public MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager userManager, RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
            : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    {}   

    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    { 
        var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
        var sub = identity.FindFirst("sub");
        if (sub == null)
            return identity; 

        identity.RemoveClaim(sub);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", user.GlobalUid.ToString()));

        return identity;
    }
}
```

The second extend IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService like so.  This will solve the issue I mentioned in the comments above.

```
public class MyClaimsService : DefaultClaimsService
{
    private readonly UserManager _userManager;

    public MyClaimsService(IProfileService profile, ILogger<DefaultClaimsService> logger, UserManager userManager) : base(profile, logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Claim> GetStandardSubjectClaims(ClaimsPrincipal subject)
    {
        var sub = subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, user?.GlobalUid.ToString() ?? sub),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.AuthenticationTime, subject.GetAuthenticationTimeEpoch().ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.IdentityProvider, subject.GetIdentityProvider())
        };

        claims.AddRange(subject.GetAuthenticationMethods());

        return claims;
    }
}
```

Add the UserClaimsPrincipleFactory to the service collection through the identity builder when adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
     {
         options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
         options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
     })
     .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>()
```

Then add the ClaimsService as a transient like so

```
services.AddTransient<IClaimsService, MyClaimsService>();
```

Now all your claims should come back as the property you provided for all tokens.  Let me know if you have any issues with this, as it is still in a testing stage for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually I don't have the time to test this. But I will test this later and if this works I will mark the answer.

Comment: No problem.  Like I said, I haven't had much test time either, but this seems to be working. Let me know how it goes or if you find a better way!

Comment: Did yo9u ever get this working?  Upvote and a mark as correct, if you have please.  Thanks!